# How to provide additional arguments to custom symbol renderer in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, symbols, renderer

I would like to generate a Highcharts scatter chart with oval markers with variable height and width.  To create the oval, I'm using a custom marker, and generating the necessary curves in the renderer.  However, the required width and height of each oval is different.  Ideally, I'd like to specify something akin to

`data:[{x:0,
       y:0,
       marker:{radius:{w:3,h:7}}
      }]`

and then use that information when creating the oval in the renderer.

However, Highcharts doesn't like the object as the radius value. Is there a way to pass arbitrary data to the renderer? I'm currently using a hack in which I pass the renderer an index into an external array via the marker radius, but I'm hoping there's a sanctioned way since this is creating some undesirable side effects.

[Current JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/LVfad/)

Appreciate any thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap drawPoints function, which uses

```
point.graphic = graphic = chart.renderer.symbol(
                        symbol,
                        plotX - radius,
                        plotY - radius,
                        2 * radius,
                        2 * radius
                    )
                    .attr(pointAttr)
                    .add(markerGroup);
```

but should your custom paramter lik rx/ry in marker, not default r / radius.

Comment: Thanks.  Makes sense, but I didn't see a hook to override that snippet. Do I have to copy the entire source of `Highcharts.Series.prototype.drawPoints` into my code, modify as you describe, and then assign back to `drawPoints`? Or is there a preferred method?